# Examine contents of Javascript variable after some action

Tags: javascript, xml, html, file, xml-parsing

I have a function that is supposed to read from a file into a variable

I want to know the validity of the reads and was wondering if there was any way I could examine the contents of the variable after the upload action has been performed.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    // Loop through the FileList
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        parser=new DOMParser();
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Print the contents of the file
                //  var span = document.createElement('span');
                xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(e.target.result,"text/xml");
                try{
                    DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
                }catch(error){
                DistributomeXML_Objects=xmlDoc.childNodes;
                }
                //document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the file
        //reader.readAsDataText(f,UTF-8);
        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
    //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("distributome").item(0).appendChild(node);


    traverseXML(false, null, DistributomeXML_Objects, distributome.nodes, distributome.edges, distributome.references, distributomeNodes, referenceNodes);
}
```

I want to check if xmlDoc is valid. What would be a good way to do this without using print statements.

Comment: You mean without `console.log`? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the console and log variables content using the

```
console.log("my variable content",variable);
```

you can see it in the browser console using firebug or the native console of chrome or opera...

Comment: what are you using for your development ?

Comment: I'm just using Chrome - do you have any suggestions?

Comment: well the chrome console is great but I suggest you to use fire fox with firebug addon take a look at it you can see more features you can debug you javascript code step by step with it

Comment: JavaScript debugging with breakpoints ("step by step") is not exclusive to Firebug, as a matter of fact, it's built into Chrome (Webkit) and Internet Explorer.